# How to convert from seconds to nanoseconds in a timeval struct?

Tags: c, timeval

I want to convert my timeval struct from seconds to nanoseconds, what is the best algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: Multiply the seconds by one billion? Although this won't give you any more precision.

Comment: http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~jglenn/702/S2008/Projects/P3/time.html should help..

Comment: Multiplication by 1000000000?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because converting from seconds to nanoseconds is a simple multiplication

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this:

```
uint64_t nanosec(struct timeval t) { /* Calculate nanoseconds in a timeval structure */ 
  return t.tv_sec * 1000000000 + t.tv_usec * 1000; 
}
```